# updateChildValues using dictionary or url

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am looking to update my firebase database atomically, thus i have been using updateChildValues. However, I have experienced some behaviour that I would like to be explained.

When I add data to the database using the following code, it works perfectly fine and new objects are added to the JSON tree under their newly generated key beneath either the ItemOwnership or ItemCategory nodes:

```
let key = rootRef.child("PostedItems").childByAutoId().key

let updateLocations = ["ItemOwnership/\(key)" : uid,
                       "ItemCategory/\(key)" : category
                      ]

rootRef.updateChildValues(updateLocations)
print("Item has been saved!")
```

However, if I use constants to hold the dictionaries, like-so:

```
let key = rootRef.child("PostedItems").childByAutoId().key

let itemOwnership = [key : uid]
let itemLocation = [key : location]

let updateLocations = ["ItemOwnership" : itemOwnership,
                       "ItemCategory" : itemLocation
                      ]

rootRef.updateChildValues(updateLocations)
print("Item has been saved!")
```

Instead of adding new values under a new autogenerated ID, the new ID and value overwrite the old ID and value, such that I can never have more than one key value pair under the ItemOwnership or ItemCategory node. Why is this happening? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working by design. When you do updateChildValues(), it is essentially doing this behind the scenes:

```
for (key, val) in updateData {
   ref.child( key ).set( val );   
}
```

So you need to pass the lowest level node in as the key in order to only replace that node.

Comment: I see, so in the latter case it is doing `ref.child(ItemOwnership).set(key:uid)`, whilst in the former it is doing `ref.child(ItemOwnership/\(key)).set(uid)` ?

Comment: Correct! You got it.

Comment: Much appreciated @Kato!